# Post not able to send data to php file [new to php]

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to php and I am saving user gps latitude and longitude usign ajax call to a php file.

echo call in html page returns the coordinates correctly but when I run the php file, it has `undefined index` error.

I have checked similar posts and found out may be this a problem of Apache server rewriting and removing php extension using some code in .htacess,  but I could not find any code in such post.

Can you help me with what is the right approach of simply sending data using POST to a php file using ajax call?

Here is my code

```js
var Latitude;
var Longitude;
getLocation();
function getLocation() {
  document.getElementById("img").src = "pic1.jpg";
  alert("geolocation");
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showposition);
  } else {
    console.log("GPS not supported");
  }
}

function showposition(position) {
  Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Location_Data.php',
    data: {
      'lat': Latitude,
      'lng': Longitude
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
      alert("Ajax function");
      alert(result);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<img alt="Click Allow" id="img" height="400" width="300">


<p id="demo">Coordinates: </p>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

php file:

```
<?php

/*
$lat= isset($_POST['lat']) ? $_POST['lat'] : null;
$lng= isset($_POST['lng']) ? $_POST['lng'] : null;
$name= isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
*/
echo "PHP file is live! \r\n";

$lng = $_POST['lng'];
$lat= $_POST['lat'];


echo "\r\n Coordinates: \r\n";
echo $lat;
echo "\r\n";
echo $lng; 


?>
```

I am showing screenshot of php file and my console which has some dev tool warning

[image: Screenshot link]

Comment: `ajax` sends an asynchronous request to your php file. So the data send only exists in this request. If you access the php file through your browser afterwards the data will not available anymore. Check the response of the ajax request in your browser console to check the data. What does your `result` contain in the alert?

Comment: Go to the Network Tab in Developer tools and Send and Catch the Ajax Request. Verify the Response

Comment: Yea result alert shows me correct latitude and longitude as well as successful run of the php file. How do I permanently save the data then? @empiric

Comment: In your php file, save the received data (e.g. a database, filesystem, or whatever storage sysem you like) and retrieve the data from there when accessing the file directly

Comment: Thanks alot! empiric , I saved the data in a text file and it was successful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In Ajax, the data is sent to the server (**POST** or **GET**) in the background, without affecting the page at all, and the response is then received by javascript in the background, again without affecting the page at all.

And thus if the page isn't affected the *Undefined Index errors* are most likely to come.

Comment: ok thanks. then how do permanently save data in the php, or in your language, affect the php page?

Comment: you can do it by Post method consisiting of form tag